# How to verify if CDH (cloudera hadoop distribution) is installed or not

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

How to check if CDH is installed or not?

If yes, than get the version number.

If someone can give me shell script to do the same it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with:

```
readlink /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH
```

Or with hadoop command:

```
hdfs version | grep "CDH" | awk -F"/" '{print $5}'
```

Comment: Thank you!. do you have any idea how to do the same for HDP or other generic ones using shell script

Comment: Please if my answer helps you, you can mark my answer as useful.

Comment: I am getting following error $ hdfs version | grep "CDH" | awk -F"/" '{print $5}'
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.NullAppender
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "NullAppender".